# Xcode 8 default build settings are broken

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8, build-settings

With Xcode 7 everything was working perfectly. For example I was able to successfully build and test Socket Rocket project.
After a made an update to Xcode 8.1 all my projects stop building since default build settings have been altered or broken.
For an example Socket Rocket doesn't build since ARC is now disabled (note that project settings remain unchanged). Another my project fails on warning that return value of function is ignored (I prefer settings `-Werror` but new warning has been enabled and so on).

I could fix build settings project by project, but it is a lot of work and quite annoying, but bigger problem is that this will impact other developers I work with and I prefer to avoid this.

So my question is how can I fix this? How can I change (fix) default build setting which are used for all projects on my machine?

My friend did update Xcode (and uses same project I have problem with) and doesn't experience this problem. Apparently something got broken when I did an upgrade of Xcode (no errors has been reported).

I have this problem for Mac OS  and iOS, in build setting Xcode when showing `levels`, most right column names are respectively `macOS default` and `iOS Default`.

[image]